# Alternate way of generating a topology from a base

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathscr{B}$ be a basis for a topology $T$ on a non-empty set $X$.

A set $U\subseteq X$ is open (i.e. an element of the $T$) if for every $x\in U$ there exists
$B\in \mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B \subseteq U$

How do we prove that $T$ is indeed a topology?

I think if $\{X\}$ is a base of $T$, then this is actually disproven. What am I missing here?

Comment: Instead of asking new questions, why don't you ask for clarifications in the previous one? Or even better, try to check the conditions that bases must satisfy?

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem. If $\mathscr{B}=\{X\}$, the only open sets are $X$ and $\varnothing$. It’s certainly true that for each $x\in X$ there is a $B\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq X$, since we may take $B=X$. And it’s vacuously true that if $x\in\varnothing$, then there is a $B\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq\varnothing$, because there is no $x\in\varnothing$ to invoke the requirement in the first place. To put is a little differently, the only way that this could be false is if there were an $x\in\varnothing$ such that no $B\in\mathscr{B}$ satisfied $x\in B\subseteq\varnothing$, and there is no such ‘bad’ $x$, because there is no $x\in\varnothing$ in the first place.

Comment: (One problem is that the quantifiers in the question are wrong. He fixes *a* topology on X and then wonders why or if  {X} is a basis for that topology... or something: it's quite messed up)

Comment: I see. How would I go about proving T is a topology?

Comment: @user40300: Just check that it satisfies the conditions defining a topology: $\varnothing\in T,X\in T$, and $T$ is closed under taking finite intersections and arbitrary unions. Or, if you already know that the topology generated by a base is the set of all unions of base elements, show that the members of $T$ are precisely the subsets of $X$ that are unions of members of $\mathscr{B}$.

Comment: I am having trouble with the arbitary unions part, If the if-then statement is true, how would I show that any arbitary union is in $T$?

Comment: I suggest reading the proof of what you want in a good textbook such as Munkres "Topology".

Comment: @user40300: Let $\mathscr{U}$ be a collection of open sets. If $x\in\bigcup\mathscr{U}$, then by definition of union there is a $U\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $x\in U$. $U$ is open, so by definition there is a $B\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$. Of course $U\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{U}$, so $x\in B\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{U}$. Thus, $\bigcup\mathscr{U}$ is open.